# How to add a new column and insert values in csv using node js?

Tags: node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I have generated a `npm-audit.csv` file by running `npm audit --json | npm-audit-csv` in cmd.

This is an example of the csv result:

| Package Name | Severity | Vulnerability | Vulnerability Found in | Adivisory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dottie | high | dottie vulnerable to Prototype Pollution | dottie | https://github.com/advisories/ABCD-11-EFG2-HI1J |

I have multiple node.js apps and I want the csv file to have each tool's name as well.

How to put the tool name in csv file using node js?

This is the result I am expecting:

| Tool Name | Package Name | Severity | Vulnerability | Vulnerability Found in | Adivisory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MyApp | dottie | high | dottie vulnerable to Prototype Pollution | dottie | https://github.com/advisories/ABCD-11-EFG2-HI1J |

Please advise me.
Thank you in advance.